# Python cant make dictionary from list of dictionaries

Tags: python, django

I have list of dictionaries as a result of django formset error:

```
[{}, {"field": ["This field is required."]}, {"field": ["This field is required."]}]
```

I want to make a dictionary where key is index of dictionary + name of field and value is error message:

```
err = formset.errors
for dict in err:
    for error in dict:
        results[str(err.index(dict))+'-'+error] = dict[error]
```

Problem is that I get only one value from err, not all. How can I solve that? Thanks

Comment: As a notice , Dont use `dict` as a variable name.

Comment: What you mean by `index+name of field` ? should be `1field`?

Comment: Please show the desired output, and what you are getting instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were pretty close. First I would use enumerate because that what it meant to do. And use iteritems(python 2.7) to iterate over the dict.:

```
for idx, _dict in enumerate(err):
    for error_key, error_value in _dict.iteritems():
        results[str(idx)+'-' + error_key] = error_value

print results
```

and I got:

> {'1-field': ['This field is required.'], '2-field': ['This field is required.']}

*As mentioned on the comments - Don't use `dict` since it's preserved word  on python.

Answer (score 0):

```
err = formset.errors
D = {}
for i in len(err):
    crr_field = err[i].keys()[0]
    error_msg  = "{field} error: {error}".format(field=crr_field,error=err[i][crr_field])
    D[i] = error_msg
```

D will be `{1:"Field field1 error: field is required",2:....}`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
results = {}
err = formset.errors
for i, my_dict in enumerate(err):
    for key, value in my_dict.items():
        results[str(i)+'-'+key] = value
```

`items()` works in python3, because `iteritems()` was removed.